# Async/await in foreach not waiting

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to use `async` and `await` in a function that uses a `forEach` loop. Annoyingly I can't get it to work. What should happen is it takes an array of event `docs`, loops through them, adds in some extra data, then pushes them to the `events` array. This `events` array is then returned from the original function. Here is my code:

```
async function getEvents() {
  ...
  var events = []
  await addExtrasToDocsForUser(docs, currentUserId, events)
  return events

}


var addExtrasToDocsForUser = (docs, currentUserId, events) => {
    return docs.forEach(async (eventDoc) => {
        const event = await addExtrasToDocForUser(eventDoc, currentUserId)
        events.push(event)
    })
}
```

What actually happens is the `getEvents()` function returns `events` as an empty array before the `forEach` loop has completed. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you combine synchronous and asynchronous functions? 
You call `await addExtrasToDocsForUser(docs, currentUserId, events)`, but your function addExtrasToDocsForUser is not `async`.

```
var addExtrasToDocsForUser = async (docs, currentUserId, events) => {
  return await docs.forEach(async (eventDoc) => {
    const event = await addExtrasToDocForUser(eventDoc, currentUserId)
    events.push(event)
  })
}
```

You want to do something like this:

```js
var someOperation = async (op0, op1) => {
 return op0+':'+op1
}

var fnWithForeach = async (docs, number, outputs)=>{
  return await docs.forEach(async (doc)=>{
 const output = await someOperation(doc, number)
 outputs.push(output) 
  })
}

async function getOutputs() {
  // ...
  var docs = ['A', 'B', 'C']
  var number = 10
  // ...
  var outputs = []
  await fnWithForeach(docs, number, outputs)
  return outputs
}

async function main() {
  // ...
  var outputs = await getOutputs()
  console.log(outputs)
  // ...
}

main()
```

Answer (score 11):

Basically, this is what happens inside `forEach`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function (callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
    callback(this[index], index, this);
  }
};
```

Actually, the real implementation is [the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill), but the bottom line is that **we are not waiting for the callback to be done**, so using a function that returns a promise won't wait for the promise to resolve everytime.

Your code is not [complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can't be sure that the following works, but it probably should act as you'd expect:

```
const addExtrasToDocsForUser = async (docs, currentUserId, events) => {
  for (let i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {
    const event = await addExtrasToDocForUser(docs[i], currentUserId);
    events.push(event);
  }
  return;
}
```

You might also want to check [this CodeBurst article on foreach + async/await](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)

Comment: In my `getEvents()` function, do I need to say `await addExtrasToDocsForUser(docs, currentUserId, events)` or can I remove the `await` there?

Comment: Keep the `await`. If you remove it, it'll just launch the promise but not wait for the promise to resolve first.

Answer (score 9):

Use `Promise.all` and `map` get all inner promises and return a single one that awaits them all:

```
const addExtrasToDocsForUser = async (docs, currentUserId, events) => {
    return Promise.all(docs.map(async (eventDoc) => {
        const event = await addExtrasToDocForUser(eventDoc, currentUserId)
        events.push(event)
    }));
}
```